# Art of computer programming 1.2.9 D

Tags: generating-functions

I was carefully reading section 1.2.9 subsection D: Change of z in a generating function. I don't understand the premises and Knuths reasoning in the marked paragraphs. First 2 paragraphs I can prove myself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you can read is a special case of the part you're having trouble with.  In the part you can read, omega (the script w looking thing) is a square root of 1, which is 1 or -1.  (Both of them can be written as complex numbers as well, 1+0i and -1+0i.)  In the two equations labeled (12), he's using these two roots (1 and -1) to extract the odd and even terms (m=2 in this case, so n mod m = r where r is 0 for even and 1 for odd).

There are 3 complex cube roots of unity: 1, -1/2 + (sqrt(3)/2)i, and -1/2 - (sqrt(3)/2)i.  In his example, he uses a complex cube root to extract every third term starting at 1.

[The wikipedia page on roots of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) might be helpful, especially the two pictures which show the 3rd and 5th roots of unity on a unit circle in the complex plane.